# MVC 3 with IE, poor bundle performance

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, performance, internet-explorer, iis-6

We have deployed an MVC 3 website on an IIS6 box. 
Everything runs fine, but the performance is abysmal.
Can anyone help me understand

- why am I getting 20 second response times to get a script bundle?

  [image: 20.4 seconds for script bundles]
- why bundled scripts are not cached by IE even if the Expires header is set?

  [image: response headers]

The site is several times faster in Chrome (I have noticed the cache behaviour is correct), but we cannot force customers to use it.
Any help would be great. I'm kind of wondering if it's a server-side setting that's forcing the bundle recompilation each request, or if it's just IE acting like usual.

Edit: as per comments request, I'm including also the bundle request headers:

[image: Request Headers]

Comment: Could you post an image of the request as well? It might help to see if the request has any prior knowledge of the script (e.g. is it sending `If-Modified-Since` or `If-None-Match`)

Comment: @AndyBrown - thank you! I will include the request screenshot shortly.

Comment: That's annoying - neither of those headers are present (I'm assuming this was a normal load and not a full refresh). If you hit a **full refresh** (Ctrl+F5) in Chrome, does it happen with the same performance, or does that bundle download in milliseconds (i.e., what does the timeline in chrome developer tools look like)

Comment: @AndyBrown - Just tested in Chrome. A full refresh includes a Pragma: no-cache header. After that, reloading the page shows the bundle is loaded from cache, <1 ms load times (instead of 10+ seconds of IE) - please note that no additional headers are included in Chrome, I assume it's recognizing the bundle url.

Comment: How fast is the full refresh's download of the bundle?

Comment: it's around 8 seconds (some 350KB in total, which is puzzling)

Comment: ok, that suggests network or server, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have different download times for a full reload between the two browsers it could be that you are doing intense computations with a client side framework like angularjs (*I have seen big performance differences from highly complex angularjs apps between the two browsers*).

If both your browsers show the same download time, it is either a network issue, or a server issue.

The IE caching could be a separate issue, break your problem into two parts - look for the cause of the slow downloads first.

All I can do now is suggest an approach to finding the issue.

#### Summary of what you know

It looks like you have:

- Server sends an `Expires` header one year from now
- When you reload the page (i.e. you don't force a full refresh using `Ctrl+F5`)

  - IE doesn't take any notice of the cache header, and when it sends it's new request it doesn't use `If-Modified-Since` or `If-None-Match`
  - Chrome behaves differently and respects the `Expires` and/or `ETag` response headers (it doesn't even make the request again for the bundle).
- **EDIT 1**: <strike>You also seem to be saying (though it would be good to see a timeline from chrome) that Chrome downloads the files faster, implying it is *not* a server-side problem.</strike> Your latest comment states that Chrome's downloads are also slow. (end edit)
- And you also seem to be saying that this behaviour is consistent (i.e. 100 requests in IE, and 100 requests in Chrome show the above behaviour with no deviations).

#### Approach

You should break this problem into two parts:

1. Why is the download so slow?

   - Is there a server-side performance problem? Look for common download times in IE and Chrome, and Firefox (it could be due to bundling/minification/compression on the server).
   - Is there a network connectivity issue (dropped packets, for instance)? Look for inconsistent download times, Start times, Request times, between requests in a given browser and the same behaviour across all browsers.
   - Is a script slowing down IE, but not Chrome (this is not uncommon, I maintain legacy sites where the scripts don't run well in IE but do in Chrome) - look at different profile results between browsers.
2. Why is the javascript not being cached in IE? Troubleshoot (1) first, then worry about this.

It is possible that the two are related, but approaching them separately will be a start. Number 1 is far easier to diagnose that 2, the top references to caching javascript in IE on the web are to *prevent* it in order to help with development.

#### Root cause diagnosis

**EDIT 1** The first thing to do is try the site from a browser on the server, or very close to the server to see if you have a network issue. (end edit)

Tools like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com), the browser developer tools, timeline and script profiler, and [YSlow](https://github.com/marcelduran/yslow) are your friend. Compare each of the following between Chrome and IE (and see what happens in Firefox as well) and spot the difference. Note: you may need to **clear the browser cache between tests**.

- browser developer tools -> script profile: see if you have a slow running script in IE compared to Chrome

  - similar analysis in a tool like [YSlow](https://github.com/marcelduran/yslow) (look for comparisons between the two browsers, not script improvements)
- request and response headers, and timeline from a normal (i.e. not full reload) page load
- request and response headers, and timeline from a full page reload (`Ctrl+F5`)
- `Start` and `Request` durations for every js file for a given browser, and between browsers (this may point to network issues)? *I note that the `Start` and `Request` alone are taking 0.6s and 1s each in IE - that is very very poor performance.*
- 5 requests, and 5 full reloads with cache clearing between (that is, don't chase a ghost - be consistent in your test methodology)

Download times should be no different between Chrome and IE with no scripts actually running so also add a control test. Assuming that your bundle files don't "do anything" (i.e. they contain functions that the page calls rather than kicking off long processes by themselves) then create a blank page in your site which *references exactly the same javascript files* - not just the bundle, but every single js reference.

With the control test you can compare pure download times and caching behaviour in IE to Chrome,  without any client side javascript running (use the developer tools profiler to verify no scripts are running). If your bundle files do kick off long running things, just temporarily disable those things by putting return statements at the top of the script and concentrate only on the download into the browser.

Comment: Amazing answer, let me diagnose the issue following your advice and I'll post here my findings. Thank you! Edit: before I forget, regarding your first point, I'm not doing anything special client-side (no templating libs etc)

Comment: Good luck. Be aware that SO is not really a "walk through troubleshooting" site - if you want good responses, try asking specific questions as parts of your bigger problem, most people won't answer questions like this one, and it even might get closed as OT.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I didn't expect walk-through troubleshooting to be honest, but rather an explanation/confirmation of the causes of such behaviour. As far as I can tell from YSlow (rating: 90) I think we can agree that issues here can be both server upload and IE caching behaviour. Those are issues that can be surely tackled separatedly. I'll mark this as answered not to incur into moderation... thank you for your time, much appreciated.

Comment: @Raine. It was no criticism, I think potentially other people might see this behaviour with MVC3 on IIS6 if you pin it down to server-side, so your solution should be recorded here and not be lost from SO. My comment (_Try and keep your questions as programming specific as possible to avoid the wrath of the close queue_) was an aside.